# ¿Como agregar permisos personalizados que dependan de un campo del modelo?

Tags: python, django, permisos, django-admin

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para varias empresas. Cada una de estas empresas va a tener un usuario administrador que es el encargado de gestionar los "contactos" de su propia empresa.
Por defecto django Admin crea 4 permisos (add, change, delete, view), pero estos permisos son demasiados globales ya que un usuario de la empresa 1 va a poder administrar los contactos de las otras empresas. La pregunta es, como puedo crear un permiso personalizado para que dependiendo de un campo en la tabla de la BD(verificar que el contacto es de su empresa) un usuario solo pueda administrar los contactos de su propia empresa.

```
#Este es el modelo usuario con el campo "empresa"
class User(AbstractUser):
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usuario_empresa',
                                   verbose_name='Empresa', null=True)



#Este es el modelo contacto con el campo empresa
class Contacto(NombreMixin, ControlClaseMixin):
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, verbose_name='Empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='empresa_contacto')
```

La idea sería que el usuario administrador que pertenece a la "Empresa 1" solo pueda administrar los contactos que pertenezcan a la "Empresa 1"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar permisos personalizados a cada modelo, sobre escribiendo la clase Meta de cada modelo

```
class Meta:
        permissions = (("see_all_contacts", "can see the entire contact data"),)
```

Debes de pasar una tupla por cada permiso personalizado

Comment: Con eso creo un nuevo permiso, pero como le digo a ese permiso lo que puede hacer el usuario al que le otorgue ese permiso

Comment: No existe una forma de que le digas a un permiso que hacer, basicamente django maneja los permisos en el sitio admin de forma estandar y agrega las funciones... los permisos personalizados son basicamente para sitio cliente donde tu le indicas que si tiene x permiso puede hacer algo.